# emulator in eclipse not loading after updating sdk to android version 7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Console shows the following message on running the app...and emulator just shows android...and nothing else..Could you please help me work it out

```
Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avd2'
[2017-07-11 08:27:58 - MeetingAssistant] Launching a new emulator with 
Virtual Device 'avd2'
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2017-07-11 08:31:15 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize 
OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2017-07-11 08:31:19 - Emulator] HAX is not working and emulator runs in 
emulation mode
[2017-07-11 08:31:19 - Emulator] emulator: device fd:544
[2017-07-11 08:31:19 - Emulator] 
[2017-07-11 08:31:19 - Emulator] emulator: VT feature is not enabled, HAXM 
not working.
[2017-07-11 08:31:19 - Emulator] 
[2017-07-11 08:31:26 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input 
failed
[2017-07-11 08:31:26 - Emulator] 
[2017-07-11 08:31:29 - MeetingAssistant] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2017-07-11 08:31:29 - MeetingAssistant] Waiting for HOME 
('android.process.acore') to be launched..
```

Comment: create new emulator and try with that.

Comment: tried that..still not loading

Comment: you should use genymotion.